# HTML Emails, text-decoration on links

Tags: outlook, gmail, href, html-email, text-decorations

I am making a html mail template and I cant figure out how to remove text-decoration completely. I works very well in Thunderbird, but not in Outlook and Gmail. In Outlook, the visited links get a different color and i Gmail all the links become blue. I want the to be black all the time.

Here is my code:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; text-align: left;">
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" href="[% doc.url %]">
        This is a link
    </a>
</span>
```

I also have a problem in Gmail, with a transaprent 1x1px spacer image ("spacer.gif") which shows with ca. 5px in height.

I have based my layout on tables, but I don't know  if it is relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your comment, style the href like this:

```
<a href="" style="color:#000001; text-decoration:none;">click here</a>
```

Gmail doesn't like pure black (#000000) or white (#FFFFFF) codes for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use html-reserved words, for black color use #000000 (and not #000).
For spacer image add `display:block;`.

> I have based my layout on tables

that's right.

Comment: I cant the color to be black, i have tried to add "color: #000000;" to the <td> around the <span>, to the <span> around the <a href> and in the <a href>. None of them will make the links black. I checked the source code from Gmail and it seems like it strips the styling: "color: #000000;" completely.